# How does Azure Instance Metadata Service (IMDS) gets the token from AAD for managed identity?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to understand a couple of things about Azure-managed identities.

If I need my app service to access a storage account then this is what I understood:

I can create a user assigned managed identity and assign it to an app service and then give the identity rbac on target resources.
And then we can use Azure identity SDK to create a ManagedIdentityCredential object and pass it to the Azure Storage SDK and then identity sdk takes care of authentication by calling IMDS.

So When a call is made to Azure Instance Metadata Service (IMDS) to get the token for msi, it internally calls AAD with client id and secret/certificate to get the token correct? But I am trying to understand what cert or secret does it use here as we don't set anything for msi?

Answer (score 0):

> it internally calls AAD with client id and secret/certificate to get the token correct? But I am trying to understand what cert or secret does it use here as we don't set anything for msi?

TLDR: Because of virtualized networking, IMDS knows which VM sent the request and can use that to validate if it's a legitimate request rather than requiring a certificate to establish which VM it's talking to.

I doubt there's a public facing explanation of how it works, not because it's proprietary in the trade secret or security sense but just because the answer is IMDS talks to a variety of internal Azure services. In the case of MSI, it talks to some of the internal services that underpin AAD.

However, the crux of your question is really getting at you're fetching a privileged secret and doing it via IMDS, how is that chain of trust established?

MSI tokens via IMDS are a way to bootstrap trust, meaning you don't need to provide any type of secret to get access or prove your identity. In the [IMDS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/instance-metadata-service?tabs=windows) it mentions that your traffic never leaves the host your VM is running on and happens over an unrouteable IP address. This gives a hint to what's actually happening.

When you use MSI you're trusting Microsoft to hand out tokens only to entities the identity is assigned to. When you make a request to 169.254.169.254, Microsoft *knows* with strict certainty which VM that request came from. That's compared against what you've requested, and if there is a valid identity then it's safe to issue a token to you.

This works because the IMDS instance you're talking to has access to metadata to confirm the identity is valid, and IMDS is authorized to talk to the identity services required to issue a new token. This is why on your side you don't see any certificate. The authorization is purely based on you used a network path only you have access to.

That's the value add that MSI is offering here, you don't need that initial certificate to be provisioned.

Answer (score -1):

*When a call is made to Azure Instance Metadata Service (IMDS) to get a token for a managed identity, it does not use a client secret or certificate. Instead, it uses the Azure environment and the identity endpoint to authenticate the request. The IMDS service is designed to provide temporary credentials without the need for any client secrets or certificates to be configured explicitly for the managed identity.*

Comment: There is a certificate. If you look at the service principal for the MI, it has at least one certificate on it. Microsoft rotates those certificates automatically behind the scenes and uses them to get tokens.

Comment: This isn't an incorrect answer, it's just incomplete. It raises the question how do environment and endpoint get used to validate? Junnas is probably correct to the best of my knowledge about that managed certificate existing, it's just that it isn't involved with how MSI in IMDS works.